# How to get the quarter from a date column in sql. The rows in date column are like 23-3-2021

Tags: sql, date

How to get the quarter from a date column in sql. The rows in date column are like 23-3-2021

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: "dates are like .." - I hope you don't mean they are stored as varchar? Please use real date datatypes when you store dates

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mysql then it's

select quarter(datecolumn) from table

datepart() for sql server

select DatePart(quarter, datecolumn) from table

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. And a date has 3 _fields_ - year, month and day.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DatePart(quarter, DateColumn)
```

If you are using Sqlserver or Postgresql (where it's `date_part`)

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.